# Autocomplete dropdown select containing form field like textbox

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, textbox

I want a autocomplete dropdown where alongside of the dropdown list, I want another form element like touchspin or textbox to enter the quantity. Just like bigbasket.com search field. [Like this in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZQmE.png). I am thinking of using https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen as autocomplete dropdown.

Anybody can guide me in the direction where I can acheive this. I have tried searching alot, but when I join the terms autocomplete, dropdown, touchspin or textfield the results are nowhere. I dont know whats it called so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery combobox autocomplete. Please refer this link https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. It might help